# ARIA - Do you need to use ARIA-EXPANDED with ARIA-HIDDEN?

Tags: wai-aria

I am new to ARIA roles.  If I have tool-tip type functionality, i.e. if someone click the question mark button more text is displayed detailing instruction on how to fill in the form field, should I be using the aria-expanded attribute, the aria-hidden attribute or both?

```
<div class="login-form-field tt-highlight">
    <div class="error-message error-style">
        <p>Sorry you have not entered anything in the field above.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10"> 
        <label for="inputTxtCustomerPostcode" class="login" />Postcode:</label>
        <input id="inputTxtCustomerPostcode" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <a title="Please enter a valid case reference tooltip" class="login-tooltip" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTxtCustomerPostcode" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseTxtCustomerPostcode" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tree tooltip">
        <div class="panel-body" role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
            <p>some text goes here for the tooltip</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [RDF model](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/img/rdf_model.svg) diagram to help:

[image: RDF Data Model Diagram]

`aria-expanded` is defined for the `treeitem` role via inheritance.

`aria-hidden` is defined for all roles, but has this caveat:

> Note: Authors are advised to avoid using aria-hidden="false" with styles or attributes that have historically prevented rendering in all modalities, such as display:none or visibility:hidden in CSS, or the hidden attribute in HTML 5. At the time of this writing, aria-hidden="false" is known to work inconsistently when used in conjunction with such features. As future implementations improve, use caution and test thoroughly before relying on this approach.

As a result, `aria-expanded` by itself should suffice.

**References**

- [WAI-ARIA Taxonomy](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/img/rdf_model)
- [WAI-ARIA RDF Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/img/rdf_model.svg)
- [aria-expanded](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.0/states_and_properties#aria-expanded)
- [aria-hidden](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.0/states_and_properties#aria-hidden)

Comment: None of the reference links work any more. He's a convenience link to the best practices https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch Fixed. Thanks!